# Restrict Amadeus flight search to max 5 non-stop, economy, return flights

Tags: amadeus

I wish to create a query to find return flights between two points on specific dates.

Based on the info [here](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference) and using test data I've managed to get this:

```
 GET("https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers?originLocationCode=SYD&destinationLocationCode=BKK&departureDate=2021-08-01&returnDate=2021-08-15&adults=1&currencyCode=CAD",
```

However, it's not clear to me as to how to restrict the results to:

- Return flights
- No stops
- Economy class
- Return max 5 flights

Answer (score 1):

You can find all available parameters for Flight Offers Search [here](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference)

- If you want a round trip (as opposed to one-way) you need to have a `returnDate` as part of your request. If you want only "return flights", well it is just a one-way trip so don't put any `returnDate`
- Set `nonStop` to true
- Set `travelClass` to `ECONOMY`
- Set `max` to `5`

The query could look like:

```
 GET("https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers?originLocationCode=SYD&destinationLocationCode=BKK&departureDate=2021-08-01&returnDate=2021-08-15&adults=1&nonStop=true&travelClass=ECONOMY&max=5")
```